# Dynamically update a youtube playlist on a website

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

OK I'm trying to develop a website that includes a youtube playlist. Later it should be possible for every person (in my local network) who visits the website to add songs to this playlist. I will use the youtube-api and probable php or python for this.

Now I've included the playlist via an `<iframe>` tag and stumbled across a big problem. If I now add more songs to this playlist (over youtube itself), they will of course only be added to the playlist on my website, when I reload the complete website. And if I just reload the div with the `<iframe>` for example, the problem is that the playlist starts all over again at the first song.

Is there a way I can dynamically update the playlist on my website? So that the playlist does not start again from the beginning, the current playing remains and new added songs are actually added "live" to the playlist?

Here the `<iframe>` tag if it helps:

```
<iframe id="playlist" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLmdXGEzOwfzb0fq7S2iP-t4i7x19R1ZN2"
        frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way I suggest is:

- *(Before updating the div which contains the `iframe`)*, you need to get both the current playing video and the current time of the playing video.<sup>1</sup>

*(Once you had added the video to the playlist and get the values I mentioned in the previous lines)*, update the div element (by modifying the `src` value of your `iframe`).

A example could be like this:

- You have a playlist which id is: `PLmdXGEzOwfzb0fq7S2iP-t4i7x19R1ZN2`.
- The current playing video is: `51iquRYKPbs`
- When you right-click on the playing video `51iquRYKPbs` you'll get the `Copy URL video at current time` option.
- Once selected the `Copy URL video at current time` option, you'lll get a URL like this:

> youtu.be/**51iquRYKPbs**?list=PLmdXGEzOwfzb0fq7S2iP-t4i7x19R1ZN2&**t=80**

Check the highlighted values - you'll need them for reload your `iframe`.

Your current iframe `src` value is as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLmdXGEzOwfzb0fq7S2iP-t4i7x19R1ZN2
```

*(No modifications yet)*.

For reload the iframe with the applied changes, set your iframe src as follows:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/51iquRYKPbs?list=PLZCHH_4VqpRhMW1K9I1hbgBRmmlWdyK3k&autoplay=1&start=80
```

*(Once you change the `src` value of your iframe, it will reload with the changes made and it will continue playing the video in the specified time)*.

The changes made to the `src` value are explained next:

- Set the videoId value of the video which was playing *(before complete the reload)*.
- Set the start value of the video for continue playing at the specified time.
- the `autoplay=1` is needed for play the video at the specified time.

---

<sup>1</sup> About how get the current playing video and the current time of the playing video is a complete new question and it will depend in which language you're handling all the YouTube stuff in your website - *(since you mentioned in your question that you will use php or python)*.

Comment: So if i understood that correctly.. this way everytime a new song is added to the playlist, the currently played song would pause for about 1 to 2 seconds because the iframe gets a new url right? I see it as a last possible solution but only if its simply not possible to do it seamlessly

Comment: I just found out it exists a "YT.PlayerState.ENDED" attribute for the youtube-iframe-api. This in combination with your suggestion might actually work. I give it a try. Source: [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en)

Comment: @Adrian about my first comment, you misunderstood - sorry for my bad english -. What I meant to say is: `once you added the video in your playlist - directly in YouTube`, you need reload the iframe - by changing the src value *(this is because the iframe with the playlist will load the videos already added in the playlist - the iframe wont search updates in the playlist as far as I know, but I might be wrong)*.

Comment: about your second comment: by using the YouTube Player API, you might add a video to the playlist, but it wont add it really in the playlist *(like the way you do when you select a video and select the option "add to playlist")* - these changes will be locally available. If you can provide in your question the code you're using, I might be able to help you further. Good luck.